# Eiffel: Creator instruction applies to target of a deferred type

Tags: eiffel

### Class A

```
deferred Class A

feature -- 

    item: X -- X is deferred

    set_item_for_some_reason (param: N)
        do
            create item.make_from_param (param)
        end

end -- class
```

### Class B

```
Class B inherit

    A

feature -- 

    item: Y -- Y not deferred inherits from X

end -- class
```

I'd like to create in the same class an attribute which will be defined in the descendent and get a `Creator instruction applies to target of a deferred type` Error which makes sens in a way of reduced context, but not in the context I intend it to do it.

For me it does make sense to be able to create an object in current deferred class, I wont have to implement in all the descendants! which will be a wrong design... something like this:

```
deferred Class A

feature -- 

    item: X -- X is deferred

    set_item_for_some_reason (param: N)
        do
            set_item_from_param (param)
        end

    set_item_from_param (param: N)
        deferred
        end

end -- class


Class B inherit

    A

feature -- 

    item: Y -- Y not deferred


    set_item_from_param(param: N)
        do
            create item.make_from_param (param)
        end

end -- class
```

Am I wrong with my design or is it a restriction which is still discussed about Eiffel compiler [as I understood](http://eiffel-software.yahoogroups.narkive.com/dTjbAYDv/creation-instruction-applies-to-target-of-a-deferred-type)? and if yes, what would be the best practice workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use generic classes. In the class `A`, the formal generic parameter has a creation constraint that the corresponding actual generic parameter should have a particular creation procedure:

```
class A [G -> X create make_from_param end] feature
    item: detachable G
    set_item_for_some_reason (param: N)
        do
            create item.make_from_param (param)
        end
end
```

A descendant class can specify an actual generic that has this creation procedure:

```
class B inherit
    A [Y]
end
```

To make sure we are on the same page, here is the code of classes `X` and `Y`:

```
deferred class X feature
    make_from_param (param: N)
        deferred
        end
end

class Y inherit
    X
create
    make_from_param
feature
    make_from_param (param: N)
        do
        end
end
```

You can add as many such descendants as you wish. The main restriction is that whenever class `A` is used, its actual generic parameter should have the specified feature as a creation one. For example, it's OK to declare a type `A [Y]`. But `A [X]` would trigger an error.

If in a descendant, the type of `item` should not be fixed yet, it's possible to propagate it, repeating the constraint on the formal generic:

```
class C [G -> X create make_from_param end] inherit
    A [G]
end
```

Comment: you're the boss! I tend not to use genericity when I can use inheritence but you're right I have to review my theory of genericity and appliance cases... I tent to use it more on languages with more restrictions as implementations and no polymorphism as workarounds...